# Writing OBD2 commands in a loop

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

I am developing a mobile app to do some OBD2 tests and monitoring via bluetooth and i want to write some OBD2 commands inside a for loop, in a interval of a second (1000ms) or even less. Is there some chance of damage the ECU of my car or some limitation (number of written commands to x ammout of time) in the way the ECU could answer to my commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not gonna do damage, if it’s too much it will more than likely just stop replying.

When programming an ecu it communicates about about 1 message per millisecond. So I’m sure a few messages every second will be nothing.

Comment: Thanks! By this way, 1 message per millisecond is very good for what i'm planning to do.

Comment: In newer cars it can be up to 0.1 ms per message.  All depends on what you're working on.  But the way all protocols are built, you'll be waiting on the car not waiting on the computer.

Comment: OBD is pretty safe in these cases. You can send how frequent you like but at the end the controller decides to response or not......

As a brainstorm, What would happen if we overload the controller with messages like what the hackers do to make a website down.

Comment: Usually these automotive modules are programmed to have a priority of operations.  For instance if you log freeze frame data too fast on cars, it will not kill engine operations it will just stop communicating or delay the comms.